# How to mirror or cdn an m3u8 stream playlist?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, cdn, m3u8

I have an m3u8 URL for a live stream and I wanna use it my website. but to reduce the bandwidth on the origin server I wanna create like a CDN on my server for it. I got a dedicated server with FFmpeg installed on Centos 7
I tried to do the following command

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i "ORIGIN_URL name_key=bitrate" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8 -timeout 180000 -s 1280x720
```

But as I tried to add it to the website using some kind of a player 
I use https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

I'm facing that the stream is always started from the starting time of the FFmpeg command while I wanna show it from the current min

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use ffmpeg at all. You already have the files, you don’t need to process them again. Just use a caching proxy like varnish.

Comment: Thanks man that was really helpful
I used varnish cache for cent os and mirror the m3u8 link as u suggested